# ld: library not found for -lgcc

Tags: c++, c, macos, gcc

I have this problem with my 'pgfortran' compiler:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/x86_64'  
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1'  
ld: library not found for -lgcc
```

This error is happening after OSX was updated to Maverick.

Comment: Just a guess: Check the permissions of the directory.

Comment: Hello! Thanks! But those directories don't exist.